# html5 canvas - rotate and move an image at the same time

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

i allready found out how to rotate an image with canvas, but im having problems creating an animation, which rotates and moves an image at the same time. This is what i already have:

```
var img;
var context;
var processID;
var i = 0;
var rectWidth = 64;
var rectHeight = 64;
window.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        processID = setInterval(draw,1000/100);
    }
    function draw() { 
        if(i <= 360) {
            context.clearRect(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.width / 2, canvas.width, canvas.height);       
            context.strokeRect(-rectWidth / 2, -rectHeight / 2, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            context.rotate(1 * Math.PI / 180);
            i++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(processID);
        }  
    }
```

So now i want my square to move to the top while rotating. I'm really lost here and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So luckily i found the answer myself:

```
var img;
var context;
var processID;
var i = 0;
var rectWidth = 64;
var rectHeight = 64;
window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    processID = setInterval(draw,1000/100);
}
function draw() { 
    if(i <= 360) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.save();
        context.translate(canvas.width / 2, i+(canvas.height / 2));
        context.rotate(i * Math.PI / 180);
        context.strokeRect(-rectWidth / 2, -rectHeight / 2, rectWidth, rectHeight);
        context.restore();
        i++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(processID);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `translate` method, or more generically the `transform` method. See [the docs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations) for a reference of what you can do, and [the wiki page for Transformation Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Examples_in_2D_graphics)